# Rangy - Module 'WrappedSelection' Not Supported

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rangy

I am trying to use Rangy in my Google Chrome extension, but I keep on receiving the error "Module 'WrappedSelection' not supported". This is a bare-bones extension so I have not implemented any code in this project other then Rangy.

Does anyone know if Rangy is compatible with a Google Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in Google Chrome extensions but I don't believe there's any reason why Rangy couldn't be used in one. I believe it's done using [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). A project called [Feltipen](http://feltipen.com/) uses Rangy in a Chrome extension.