# Rangy Modules Not Supported In Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rangy

I am trying to use Rangy in Chrome, and it seems that the Serializer and WrappedSelection modules are not supported by Chrome. I am unsure if I did not init() Rangy properly, or if I did some other mistake. I ran console.log(rangy.modules) which is how I found out that the Serializer and WrappedSelection are unsupported.

I have created an empty Chrome extention, and in manifest.js included the 7 required Rangy js files, and jQuery.js. Below are the contents of my script.js:

```
function rangyTest() {

    rangy.init();
    console.log(rangy.modules);

    var value;

    $("body").append( "<input type=\"button\" id=\"serializeButton\" value=\"Serialize selection\">" );
    $("body").append( "<input type=\"button\" id=\"deserializeButton\" value=\"Restore selection\">" );

    $('#serializeButton').click(function() {
        value = rangy.serializeSelection();
    });

    $('#deserializeButton').click(function() {
        rangy.deserializeSelection(value);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs done using [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). See also [Rangy - Module 'WrappedSelection' Not Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611955/rangy-module-wrappedselection-not-supported/9699998#9699998)